# backbone.js and routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm not sure if either im doing something wrong, But I have a function in my router set up like so:

```
    ":page/"    : "page",
    ":page/:subpage"    : "subpage"
```

but if the user were to access :page without the forward slash my page function breaks.
I've tried adding another function without the forward slash and it breaks it somehow.

```
  ie: ":page":"page"
      ":page/":"page"
      ":page/:subpage/":"subpage"
```

Comment: I don't think it should be your concern if user mistype the page url..
as if you were trying to visit www.example.com but were mistakenly type www.example.co

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it breaks somehow"?

Comment: @Lukas if I have both :page and :page/ it runs the page function twice which breaks the site.

Comment: Lastest version (at least) of Backbone should ignore trailing `/` and work with or without. Which version are you using?

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Backbone.js 0.9.2

Comment: @SimonBoudrias just upgraded. Same issue.

Comment: Can you show more code, a live example would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the following to fix the issue:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
      'page(/)': 'page',
      ":page:subpage(/)"    : "subpage"
    }
});
```